# Partial view does not return any data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

It's my first practice at getting data from a partial view but I don't know what's going wrong in my code. I cant get any data.

In my main view folder I created a partial view named `Fault_statPartial` and in my main view I call it like below:

```
<div>
      @{ Html.RenderPartial("Fault_statPartial"); }
</div>
```

and in my partial view I have a button and when I click on it, it's supposed to return data. Here is the partial view code:

```
@model string 
<html>
<head>
 <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
 <title></title>

  </head>
  <body>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/KndoTst/jquery.min.js")"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/KndoTst/kendo.all.min.js")"></script> 
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/KndoTst/jquery.maskedinput.js")"></script>                 
  @section Scripts{   
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/KndoTst/jquery.min.js")"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/KndoTst/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>  
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/KndoTst/jquery.maskedinput.js")"></script>  

  <button  type="button" class="buttonForMonthlydailyYearly" id="faultstat" >FaultStat</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">

        var turbineName = [];
        var finalResultYear = [];
        var data = [];
        var data_wind = [];
        var finalResultWind = [];
        //DropDownList
        var drp = "s";
        var topTenResultOfMonth = null;
        var topTenResultOfYear = null;
        var topTenResultOfDay = null;
        var selcted;
        var tmp;
        var tmpString;

        $("#faultstat").click(function (e) {
            debugger;
            tmp = $("#multiselect").val();
            tmpString = tmp.toString();

            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("faultStatstics","Ranking")",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ "id": tmpString }),
                    success: function (result) {
                        debugger;
                        var productionResult = result.sumOfDay[0].m_energy_prod;
                        var productionMonthresult = result.sumOfMonth;
                        var productionofYear = result.sumofyear;
                        //  debugger;
                        $("#production").empty();
                        $("#production").append(productionResult);

                        $("#monthProduction").empty();
                        $("#monthProduction").append(productionMonthresult);

                        $("#yearProduction").empty();
                        $("#yearProduction").append(productionofYear);
                    }
                   });
           });
     </script>
       }
      </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Html.Partial returns a String. Html.RenderPartial calls Write internally and returns void

Comment: What *specifically* do you mean by "return data"?  How *exactly* does this code fail?  We can't see your screen, and the question isn't really clear.

Comment: check the network/console in chrome...what message you get after clicking **faultstat** button

Comment: Hmm, that view doesn't look like a partial view with the `html`, `body` and all those `script` tags

Comment: @David in my question in the second part(partial view) i have defined a button and javascript part below,i call this partial view in my view as i showed ,first of all i cant see the button i defined which html tag,i don't know why!

Comment: @Rajaji  should i define the button in my partial view?when i define it there,i cant see it when i run the project,

Comment: @phuzi should i remove all those you mean?

Comment: click on the button where it is... press F12 and see what the conole error is showing on chromer

Comment: @moris1983, You should only include the bits necessary for the partial. This doesn't feel like a partial view as the JS references element Id's that aren't in the view `#multiselect`, `#production`, etc. You'd probably already have Kendo UI and jQuery already included as part of your parent views or `_Layout.cshtml`. Just seems backwards.

Comment: @phuzi thanks a million it works when I removed all those